# Test View Yield in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a view layout file that currently yields:

Layout.html.slim:

```
html
  header
    [content]
  = yield :page_content
  footer
    [content]
```

and then a template file that follows the same format.

template.html.slim:

```
- content_for :page_content
  #hello
```

I want to be able to test the content of the template without testing any content on the layout. I have found that if I create a rake layout file I can do the following in rspec:

```
describe "template.html.slim", type: :view do
  it "should render a div" do
    render template: 'template', layout: 'test_yielder'
    expect(rendered).to have_tag("#hello")
  end
end
```

where `test_yielder` is a one line file:

```
= yield :page_content
```

While this gets the job done, I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to test the content of `template` without needing to create an extra `test_yielder` file and only change how I call the `render` function?

Does a cleaner way exist?

Comment: any news on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually test the output of a template when it is rendered by a controller.

Following your approach you can refer to [view_spec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-0/docs/view-specs/view-spec).

> View specs live in spec/views and render view templates in isolation.
>
> ```
> # app/views/widgets/widget.html.erb
> <h2><%= @widget.name %></h2>
>
>
> # spec/views/widgets/widget.html.erb_spec.rb
> require "spec_helper"
>
> describe "rendering the widget template" do
>   it "displays the widget" do
>     assign(:widget, stub_model(Widget, name: "slicer"))
>
>     render template: "widgets/widget.html.erb"
>     rendered.should contain("slicer")
>   end
> end
> ```

This would work already without taking in consideration any layout. Eventually, you can specify `render template: 'something', layout: false` but is not really needed.

I would say that this is already a clean solution.

You can eventually add an helper module in your test suite if you repeat this action several time (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200096/set-variable-once-for-all-examples-in-rspec-suite-without-using-a-global-variab/46202002#46202002))

if your `template.html.slim` is correct, your test should work as expected. (I found this pretty old issue on [slim repo](https://github.com/slim-template/slim/issues/176) for reference)

Comment: was this answer helpful?